# I've tried to update tkinter label from another function every time I pressed a button but it's not working as I wish it to work! Please Guide me

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button, tkinter-label

I'm trying to update my question label,result label everytime I press the submit buttn but it isn't working. It's not showing any error but it's not updating all the time but only a few times it's updating. Please help me.

```py
def submit():#to submit answer by user and check answer and create next question
        global timeleft,user_ans,t2,t1,ori_ans,data,player_name,question_lab,result_lab,answer_entry,q,res
        t2=datetime.now()      
        try: # to get only integer input
            user_ans=int(answer_entry.get())
        except:
            mb.showerror('Wrong type','Enter only number')
        
        if ori_ans==user_ans:
            data[player_name][2]+=1
            data[player_name][1]+=1
            #tem='Your answer is correct and\n time taken is '+str((t2-t1).total_seconds())+'s'
            res.set('Your answer is correct and\n time taken is '+str((t2-t1).total_seconds())+'s')
            result_lab.update()
            #result_lab.config(bg='#EFF0F1',text=tem,font='ALGERIAN 20',fg='#38F70D')
            #tem=''
            #mb.showinfo('Time Taken',)
            update_json()
        elif ori_ans!=user_ans:
            data[player_name][3]+=1
            data[player_name][1]-=1
            #tem='Your answer is incorrect'
            res.set('Your answer is incorrect')
            result_lab.update()
            #result_lab.config(bg='#EFF0F1',text=tem,font='ALGERIAN 20',fg='#F71B0D')
            #tem=''        
            update_json()
        answer_entry.delete(0,END)
    
        n1=randint(1,10)
        n2=randint(1,10)
        operations=['+','-','*']
        r.shuffle(operations)
        question=str(n1)+operations[1]+str(n2)
        print(question,operations)
        q.set(question)
        question_lab.update()
        #question_lab.config(bg='#EFF0F1',text=question,fg='blue')            
        ori_ans=eval(question)
        #r.shuffle(operations)
        #operations=operations[1:]+operations[:1]
        answer_entry.focus_set()
        t1=datetime.now()
    
    
    
    def easy_classic():#a mode in my GAME to create a new window
        for item in root.winfo_children():
            item.destroy()   # to destroy previous windows
        global game_p,question_lab,answer_entry,result_lab,t1,ori_ans,lab,q,res #variable i used
        easy=1
        lab=Label(root,image=game_p)
        lab.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
        quit_but=Button(lab,text="QUIT",bg="#EFF0F1",fg='#E9B92E',font='ANDROID 20',command=quit_game)
        quit_but.pack(side="bottom",padx=5,pady=5)
        instruction_lab=Label(lab,text='Write your response and press Enter',font='ALGERIAN 20',bg="#EFF0F1")
        instruction_lab.pack(anchor='nw',padx=10,pady=20)
        q=StringVar()
        q.set('1+1')
        question_lab=Label(lab,textvariable=q,font='ARIAL 20',bg='#EFF0F1')
        question_lab.pack(anchor='nw',padx=20,pady=20)
    
        #question_lab.config(bg='#EFF0F1',text='1+1')
        ori_ans=2
        t1=datetime.now()
        answer_entry=Entry(lab,w=20)
        #lab.bind('<Return>',start)
        answer_entry.pack(anchor='nw',padx=20,pady=20)
        submit_but=Button(lab,text='SUBMIT',font='ANDROID 20',bg='#EFF0F1',command=submit)
        submit_but.pack(anchor='nw',padx=20,pady=20)
        res=StringVar()
        res.set('')
        result_lab=Label(lab,textvariable=res,font='ARIAL 20',bg='#EFF0F1')
        result_lab.pack(anchor='nw',padx=10,pady=20)
        answer_entry.focus_set()
```

Comment: Why do you put the widgets inside `lab` (a `Label` widget) instead of `root`?

Comment: Because I think I can't add a background image to root so I put widgets inside a Label

Comment: Although `Label` can be used as a container, but it is not designed for this.  That is the cause of the weird behaviour.  Try putting those widgets in `root` instead.

Comment: ok sure thing. I'll try that and let you know and thanks for your response.